# Swapping struct array elements

Tags: c, pass-by-reference, swap, pass-by-value

I have difficulty applying the pass by reference and pass by value separation in structs.How can I swap the elements of the fixed size struct array as below.

```
struct try{
   int num;
   char name[10];
 };
 int main(){
    struct try book[3];
    void swapper(/********/);//  <-what should be the argument of this function
  }
  void swapper(/********/){//swap second and third element of struct array
   /*how the swap may be done?
   temp=book[2];
   book[2]=book[3]; 
   temp=book[3];*/

  }
```

Comment: Is this c or c++? C only supports pass by pointers, not reference. Your syntax is also wrong. The word 'try' is reserved in c++ and your call to swapper in main is not a call but a forward declaration.

Comment: it is in C @StewartSmith.Could you please explain more with an example,i did not find a proper example about it on web..

Comment: @StewartSmith: "pass by reference" is a general programming term and not specific to C++ references. Only in C++ is the term specific to C++ references. In C, it is equivalent to "pass by pointer". Also, since the question is tagged "c", so there is nothing wrong with using the identifier name `try`.

Comment: Note that attempting to read `book[3]` for the array with 3 elements is undefined.  For `struct try book[3]`, the valid indices are 0, 1, and 2.

Comment: my bad ur right @WilliamPursell.should i edit the question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to do what you're asking.  One approach:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct try {
        int num;
        char name[10];
};

void
swapper(struct try *a, int b, int c)
{
        struct try tmp = a[b];
        a[b] = a[c];
        a[c] = tmp;
}

void
display(const struct try *t, size_t count)
{
        while( count-- ){
                printf("%d: %s\n", t->num, t->name);
                t += 1;
        }
}

int
main(void) {
        struct try book[] = {
                { 1, "foo"},
                { 2, "bar"},
                { 3, "baz"}
        };
        display(book, sizeof book / sizeof *book);
        swapper(book, 1, 2);
        display(book, sizeof book / sizeof *book);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, finally, is there a special reason you initialize struct in main as an example?

Comment: Reading uninitialized data is undefined behavior, so for the example the data must be initialized.  Doing it this way seems simplest.